# Change color of spelling errors in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, ide, spell-checking

This there a way to change the color of spelling errors in Eclipse (Galileo)? The default red underlining is indistinguishable from the normal error underlining.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As mentioned in [bug 157283](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=157283), you can change the spelling error link:

```
Editors > Text Editors > Annotations, line "Spelling Errors"
```

The color you will choose for the "Native Problem Underline" will be different from the one used for regular "Errors".

Answer (score 0):

There is guide, how to do programmatically in RCP plugin. [Java Code Examples for org.eclipse.jface.text.source.ISharedTextColors](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.eclipse.jface.text.source.ISharedTextColors) The color is not possible to set up in Marker (IMarker interface) nor in IPreferenceStore. It must be done due

```
ISharedTextColors sharedColors = EditorsPlugin.getDefault().getSharedTextColors();
```